# HTTP2/SPDY configuration in wildfly9

Tags: wildfly, http2

I'm trying to configure HTTP2/SPDY in wildlfy 9. how can i configure/test the same using wildfly 9.

I have developed login page using JSF 2.0. using this i want to check this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step guide for enabling HTTP2/SPDY in WildFly 9

http://undertow.io/blog/2015/03/26/HTTP2-In-Wildfly.html

Comment: thanks. now i have enabled http/2 in wildlfly 9. do we have any tool test and compare the performance of http2/spdy.